# UITableView refresh data in Navigation Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have an UITableView in viewController 1. So when I hit a row it sends me to Viewcontroller2 Here I have a button which adds or delete a value of a row of the UITableView from ViewController1.

So when I delete a value and i Return to ViewC 1, I still have the row highlighted, and If I return to the main view and re enter to this ViewC 1 it is deleted... How I can do to refresh the tableView when I return from Viewcontroller2 by a back Button. All of this is in a Navigation View controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

to reload the data of your table view.

```
[yourTableView reloadData]; //to reload
```

in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method in your ViewController1, add this code to remove the highlight immediately after you push or navigate to VC2.

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
```

Comment: I tried to reload data.. But I don't know where to add it... When we push back.. What methodes is turned on? viewdidload?

Comment: if you want to reload the table after you delete object, you can add the reloadData in viewDidAppear , not in viewDidLoad, make a if statement in your viewDidAppear like, if(Viecontroller2 deleted item){[tableView reloadData];}

Comment: or save the count of your objects in VC1 before you go to the VC2, then in your if statement in viewDidAppear , if(savedCountBeforePush != newObjectCount){ //reloadData }